# Regression model estimates vary depending on method of regression selected (stepwise/enter) with same predictor variables (SPSS)?

Tags: multiple-regression, spss

I am building a model for prediction with around 15 independent and one dependent variable.  If I run a stepwise model (I understand the disadvantages of doing this) on the data, I get a set of predictors and the model parameter estimates.  If I take the independent variables that the stepwise model selected and put them in a model using the "enter" function, I get different model estimates (sum of squares, R2 and coefficients).  It is essentially the same model. For example, if you do the stepwise on A, B, C, D and E, and A, B, and C are added by the stepwise algorithm the model you then have with the stepwise procedure is Y=A+B+C.  When I enter Y=A+B+C into a model (not using stepwise) I get different model parameters (Sum of Squares, R2), and different coefficients for A, B, and C.

My understanding is that it should be exactly the same overall model.  Can anyone help please?
The output and syntax are here:

[image: SPSS output one]

[image: SPSS output two]

Comment: It is strange. Can you present the spss syntax and some data, to reproduce the finding?

Comment: You used listwise deletion of missing cases in both analyses. But in the 1st analysis you had more variables with missing data than in the 2nd. Hence the two analyses got to be based on not quite the same sample of cases. Look at _total df_ the values differ.